# Xamarin and android pushmesages

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement pushmesages for my xamarin android app. I have installed xamarin google play service version 26 via nuget. However when I call this

```
int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

I get a method not found exception. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Did u find a solution to this? I'm also facing the same issue for the past one week. I am getting a MissingMethodException. Please let me know if you have resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

To check if GooglePlayServices are available, use :

```
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable (this);
```

Did you follow this guide ?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/

Comment: I tried but when compiling I get that the methods you suggests are obsolete

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, I get an method not found when trying this. I suspect I might be missing something since it cant find the methods

Comment: You may need to add the play services dependency. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup